# Did the White House hold any Yazidi religious festivities during the Obama administration?

Tags: united-states, president, barack-obama

During the Obama administration, were any Yazidi religious festivities held in the White House?

Also, what is the most populous religion (ideally worldwide but US-based is also ok) that has religious festivities, but hasn't had any celebrated in the White House during the Obama administration?

Comment: If the white house celebrated religious festivities of every niche religion on Earth the president would get even less done than he already does.

Comment: @easymoden00b - you make it sound like that's a *bad* thing

Comment: We need more Pastafarian events.